# LaunchScreen images not showing on device, only in the emulator

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, meteor

i am working on a mobile app with Meteor, and i am having some trouble with the launchScreens images, I am only trying to make it work with the iPhone 6 plus at the moment and although it works fine in the 6plus emulator, when i run it on the actual device the launchScreens defaults to the meteor icon, if anyone could help would be fantastic.

Here is my mobile-config.js file ...

```
App.icons({
  // iOS
  'iphone_2x': 'resources/icons/icon-180x180.png',
  'iphone_3x': 'resources/icons/icon-180x180.png',
  'iphone6p':  'resources/icons/icon-180x180.png'


});

App.launchScreens({

  'iphone6p_portrait': 'resources/splash/splash-1242x2208@3x.png',
  'iphone6p_landscape': 'resources/splash/splash-2208x21242@3x.png',
});
```

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but my project has the files in `public/res/` and that works ok

Comment: I guess it shouldn't as the icon is loaded ok from this folder and as mentioned even the launch screen works although only in the emulator...